# Flutter application like social Media

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

So Iam writing an app using flutter and firebase, where users are able to upload images with caption, the images are stored in firebase storage with a unique image name, and this image name is used to save the data of who uploaded it and the caption into the database. Now on the main page, all the images ever uploaded are shown, along with the caption and username.
The problem Iam facing is that, as I scroll down the pictures below get loaded one by one.. but then when i scroll back up again the images have to get loaded again. Is there anyway to avoid this.

I have used a SingleChildScrollview widget

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to avoid this. What have you tried? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

You can use, `fast_cached_network_image: ^1.2.0`, package to cache your images.

This way before fetching images from F. Storage, the package will if it already exists in the local storage **(cache)**. If it does, the it would display it from the local storage, and wouldn't fetch images again. This will also reduce the ***bandwidth expenses***.

You can view the documentation here **(it simple and straight-forward)** :
https://pub.dev/packages/fast_cached_network_image

Codes Implementation :

```
SizedBox(
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        child: FastCachedImage(
          url: url1,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          fadeInDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          errorBuilder: (context, exception, stacktrace) {
            return Text(stacktrace.toString());
          },
          loadingBuilder: (context, progress) {
            debugPrint(
                'Progress: ${progress.isDownloading} ${progress.downloadedBytes} / ${progress.totalBytes}');
            return Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  if (progress.isDownloading && progress.totalBytes != null)
                    Text(
                        '${progress.downloadedBytes ~/ 1024} / ${progress.totalBytes! ~/ 1024} kb',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                  SizedBox(
                      width: 120,
                      height: 120,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          value: progress.progressPercentage.value)),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `fast_cached_network_image`, but the problem with `fast_cached_network_image` is that it caches all the images with the same duration. If you have a social Media-ish platform, you don't want to cache images on the Discover page, for 30 days. Cause it would occupy the user's local storage without any reason, because the user might just view an image only once on the Discover page, and never see it again.

But you can assign a custom duration to each image with `cached_network_image: ^3.3.1` and `flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.1`.

Maybe 36 hours for **Discover Page** and 7/14 days for **Following Page**

**Disclaimer**

1. I don't know if it would overwrite or cache newly, the image that is the same as the one already cached, but with a different duration assigned.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl: image,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      cacheManager: CacheManager(
                                        Config(
                                          '${image}',
                                          stalePeriod: const Duration(hours: 36),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(
                                        child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 24, color: colorProvider.secondText),
                                      ),
                                      progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 30,
                                          width: 30,
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            strokeWidth: 1,
                                            color: colorProvider.firstText,
                                            value: downloadProgress.progress,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
```